# Comparing form data not works for check box and radio button

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the code below to see if the user is changing any form elements.

```
var content = [];
$(":input").each(function(i,item){
  content[i] = $.trim($(item).val()) || $(item).prop("checked");
    $(item).on('input, change', function(data) {
        var currentVal = $.trim($(this).val());
        if(currentVal != content[i]) console.log("changed");
        else console.log("no change");
    })
});

console.log(content);
```

It works fine, except for radio and checkbox controls. How to check for changes in those?
Here is the sample I made in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWDFv/) , any one suggest me the best way please?

---

I modified the function as per yckart suggestion it woks fine. but i am not getting the live update as like i am getting as interacting with check box or radio button. if any one suggest / correct my function appreciated.

Here is my function:

```
var content = [];
$(":input").each(function (i, item) {
    if (!item.value.match(/on|off/)) {
        content[i] = $.trim($(item).val())
    } else {
        content[i] = $(item).prop("checked");
    }
    $(item).on('input, change', function (data) {
        var currentVal = !$(this).val().match(/on|off/) ? $.trim($(this).val())  : $(this).prop("checked") ;
        console.log(currentVal);
        if (currentVal != content[i]) console.log("changed");
        else console.log("no change");
    })
});
```

Thanks for all...

Comment: `var currentVal = $(this).prop("checked") || $.trim($(this).val());` seems to do the trick.

Comment: i tried, but no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long struggle, I found a solution for your problem.

You need to move the `OR` condition inside the if statement `.on()` method.

```
var content = [];
$(":input").each(function (i, item) {
    content[i] = $.trim($(item).val());
    $(item).on('input, change', function (data) {
        var currentVal = $.trim($(this).val());
        if (currentVal != content[i] || $(item).prop("checked")) alert("changed");
        else alert("no change");
    })
});
```

**Reason:** You getting the value of the `input` fields, **I'm not sure why the value for `radio` and `checkbox` are always "on"**.

But for `radio` and `checkbox` it would be better to use their `checked` property.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/JcC3p/1/) for your reference.

Hope you understand.

**EDIT:** The default value of radio and checkbox is always "on", ***even if it is checked the value won't change.***

Comment: @3gwebtrain I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, `checkboxes` and `radio`-inputs have a `value` too (`"on"` & `"off"`). So simply check that the value isn't one of them:

```
var content = [];
$(":input").each(function (i, item) {
    if (!item.value.match(/on|off/)) {
        content[i] = $.trim(item.value)
    } else {
        content[i] = $(item).prop("checked");
    }
    $(item).on('input change', function (data) {
        var currentVal = $.trim(this.value);
        if (currentVal != content[i]) console.log("changed");
        else console.log("no change");
    })
});

console.log(content);
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/VWDFv/4/

Comment: But on click of checkbox only works on change, in case if i re-check not console the status properly